# Writing To Many Tables On Different Threads

Tags: c#, task, sqlbulkcopy

I am consuming a large csv file with a lot of columns.  I would like to split that file into n different types objects and then bulk insert those different objects into n different tables.  I would like to optimize as much as possible and not hold the entire csv file in memory while I writing to the db. If there is an error writing to 1 table, all tables must rollback their transactions.  I am passing the token source around because in the event that 1 table has an issue, I would like all other tables to stop processing and rollback.

To simplify the object creation/definition I am using ExpandoObjects.

The TableDetails class holds the table name, SqlConnection, and the transaction that will be used to write to a table.

I have included the ObjectDataReader that implements IDataReader to facilitate sending an IEnumerable through a SqlBulkCopy.

Why is it that when I run my Dummy SaveToDb Method, all 3 tables get their own thread to make and write to console, but when I run the real SaveToDb method, all work is done on 1 thread?

What do i need to do to get the same behavior i get on my test method?

dummy tables created as follows

```
create table Table1(Column1 int)
create table Table2(Column1 int)
create table Table3(Column1 int)
```

Main Work Here

```
    void Main()
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        
        var sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Some Connection String");
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        var sqlConnection2= new SqlConnection("Some Connection String");
        sqlConnection2.Open();
        var sqlConnection3 = new SqlConnection("Some Connection String");
        sqlConnection3.Open();
        
        var details = new List<TableDetails>()
        {
            new TableDetails(){ TableName = "Table1", Connection = sqlConnection1, Transaction = sqlConnection1.BeginTransaction(), ColumnMap = new Dictionary<int,string>(){{0, "Colunm1"}}},
            new TableDetails(){ TableName = "Table2", Connection = sqlConnection2, Transaction = sqlConnection2.BeginTransaction(), ColumnMap = new Dictionary<int,string>(){{1, "Colunm1"}}},
            new TableDetails(){ TableName = "Table3",  Connection = sqlConnection3, Transaction = sqlConnection3.BeginTransaction(),ColumnMap = new Dictionary<int,string>(){{2, "Colunm1"}}},
        };
        
        var lines = GetLines(100);
    
        var tasks = lines
            .SelectMany(e => SplitUp(e, details))
            .GroupBy(e => e.Item1)
            .Select(e => new { e.Key, Value = e.Select(v => MakeExpando(v.Item2, v.Item1)) })
    //      .Select(e => SaveToDbTest(e.Key, e.Value));
            .Select(e => SaveToDb(e.Value, e.Key, tokenSource));
    
        Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
        
        foreach (var detail in details)
        {
            detail.Transaction.Commit();
            detail.Connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<string> GetLines(int size)
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            yield return $"{rand.Next(1, 100)},{rand.Next(1, 100)},{rand.Next(1, 100)}";
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<(TableDetails, string)> SplitUp(string line, List<TableDetails> details)
    {
        foreach (var detail in details)
        {
            yield return (detail, line);
        }
    }
    
    public ExpandoObject MakeExpando(string line, TableDetails details)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread ID:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} Making Expando for Table {details.TableName}");
        
        var items = line.Split(',');
        dynamic retVal = new ExpandoObject();
        var r = retVal as IDictionary<string, object>;
        
        object value;
        foreach(var map in details.ColumnMap)
        {
            value = items[map.Key];
            r.Add(map.Value, value);
        }
        
        return retVal;
    }
    
    public Task SaveToDbTest(TableDetails details, IEnumerable<ExpandoObject> items)
    {
        var retVal = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
         {
             foreach (var i in items)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine($"Thread ID:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} Saving To Table {details.TableName} => {i}");
             }
         });
    
        return retVal;
    }
    
    private async Task SaveToDb<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, TableDetails details, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource) where T : IDictionary<string, object>
    {
        var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(details.Connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, details.Transaction);
    
        try
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = details.TableName;
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 20;
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120).TotalSeconds;
            bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
    
            var reader = new ObjectDataReader<T>(items, details.ColumnMap.Count());
    
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
    
            await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(reader, tokenSource.Token);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"completed db write in {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.GetType() != typeof(TaskCanceledException))
                tokenSource.Cancel();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Table Details

```
    public class TableDetails
    {
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }
        public SqlTransaction Transaction { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, string> ColumnMap {get; set;}
    }
```

And an IDataReader

```
    public class ObjectDataReader<TData> : IDataReader where TData : IDictionary<string, object>
    {
        private IEnumerator<TData> _dataEnumerator;
        private Dictionary<int, string> _indexToName;
    
    
        public ObjectDataReader(IEnumerable<TData> data, int propertyCount)
        {
            _fieldCount = propertyCount;
            _dataEnumerator = data.GetEnumerator();
        }
    
        #region IDataReader Members
    
        public void Close()
        {
            Dispose();
        }
    
        public int Depth => 1;
    
        public DataTable GetSchemaTable()
        {
            return null;
        }
    
        public bool IsClosed => _dataEnumerator == null;
    
        public bool NextResult()
        {
            return false;
        }
    
        public bool Read()
        {
            if (IsClosed)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name);
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread ID:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} Reading next item");
            return _dataEnumerator.MoveNext();
        }
    
        public int RecordsAffected => -1;
    
        #endregion
    
        #region IDisposable Members
    
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    
        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_dataEnumerator != null)
                {
                    _dataEnumerator.Dispose();
                    _dataEnumerator = null;
                }
            }
        }
    
        #endregion
    
        #region IDataRecord Members
    
        public int GetOrdinal(string name)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public object GetValue(int i)
        {
            if (_dataEnumerator == null)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name);
    
            var item = _dataEnumerator.Current;
    
            if (_indexToName == null)
            {
                _indexToName = item
                    .Select((e, id) => new { Index = id, e.Key })
                    .ToDictionary(k => k.Index, v => v.Key);
            }
    
            if (_indexToName.Count <= i)
                return null;
    
            return item[_indexToName[i]];
        }
    
        private int _fieldCount;
        public int FieldCount => _fieldCount; //throw new NotImplementedException(); // s_propertyAccessorCache.Value.Accessors.Count;
    
        #region Not Implemented Members
    
        public bool GetBoolean(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public byte GetByte(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public long GetBytes(int i, long fieldOffset, byte[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public char GetChar(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public long GetChars(int i, long fieldoffset, char[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public IDataReader GetData(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public string GetDataTypeName(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public DateTime GetDateTime(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public decimal GetDecimal(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public double GetDouble(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public Type GetFieldType(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public float GetFloat(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public Guid GetGuid(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public short GetInt16(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public int GetInt32(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public long GetInt64(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public string GetName(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public string GetString(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public int GetValues(object[] values)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public bool IsDBNull(int i)
        {
            var val = GetValue(i);
            return val == null;
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public object this[string name]
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    
        public object this[int i]
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    
        #endregion
    
        #endregion
    }
```

Output when writing to db.

```
    Thread ID:60 Reading next item
    Thread ID:60 Making Expando for Table Table1
    Thread ID:60 Reading next item
    Thread ID:60 Making Expando for Table Table1
    ...
    Thread ID:60 Reading next item
    Thread ID:60 Making Expando for Table Table2
    Thread ID:60 Reading next item
    ...
    Thread ID:60 Making Expando for Table Table3
    Thread ID:60 Reading next item
    Thread ID:60 Making Expando for Table Table3
    Thread ID:60 Reading next item
```

Output when writing to console.

```
    Thread ID:62 Making Expando for Table Table2
    Thread ID:71 Making Expando for Table Table3
    Thread ID:69 Making Expando for Table Table1
    Thread ID:62 Saving To Table Table2 => System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject
    Thread ID:62 Making Expando for Table Table2
    ...
    Thread ID:71 Saving To Table Table3 => System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject
    Thread ID:71 Making Expando for Table Table3
    ...
    Thread ID:62 Making Expando for Table Table2
    Thread ID:62 Saving To Table Table2 => System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject
    Thread ID:62 Making Expando for Table Table2
    Thread ID:62 Saving To Table Table2 => System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject
    Thread ID:62 Making Expando for Table Table2
```

Comment: `await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false);`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of colleges pointed out to me that there was a difference between my SaveToDBTest method, and my SaveToDB method. Namely that the SaveToDbTest created a new task, and STARTED IT.  Task.WhenAll() enumerates and starts the tasks one by one.

the following code change gets everything running on a separate thread.

```
    var tasks = lines
        .SelectMany(e => SplitUp(e, details))
        .GroupBy(e => e.Item1)
        .Select(e => new { e.Key, Value = e.Select(v => MakeExpando(v.Item2, v.Item1)) })
        .Select(e => Task.Run(() => SaveToDb(e.Value, e.Key, tokenSource)));
```